# Calculating a delta of years from a date

Tags: perl, datetime, date

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the year of birth for records when given the age to two decimals at a given date - in Perl.

To illustrate this example consider these two records:

```
date, age at date
25 Nov 2005, 74.23
21 Jan 2007, 75.38
```

What I want to do is get the year of birth based on those records - it should be, in theory, consistent. The problem is that when I try to derive it by calculating the difference between the year in the date field minus the age, I run into rounding errors making the results look wrong while they are in fact correct.

I have tried using some "clever" combination of int() or sprintf() to round things up but to not avail. I have looked at Date::Calc but cant see something I can use.

p.s. As many dates are pre-1970, I cannot not unfortunately use UNIX epoch for this.

Comment: How many days does each hundredth represent?  (Several answers are possible.)

Comment: pre-1970 are not a problem: the Unix time() is a signed integer.

However, there is a better reason to not use it: leap years, leap seconds...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl's `gmtime` and `localtime` functions have no problem handling negative input and dates before 1970.

```
use Time::Local;
$time = timegm(0,0,0,25,11-1,2005-1900);          # 25 Nov 2005
$birthtime = $time - (365.25 * 86400) * 74.23;    # ~74.23 years
print scalar gmtime($birthtime);                  # ==> Wed Sep 2 11:49:12 1931
```

The actual birthdate could be different by a few days, since one one-hundredth of a year only gives you a resolution of 3-4 days.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work fine. I was using Date::Calc which seems to have a problem handling pre 1970 epoch dates I think. 

The resolution is not an issue as I will just be comparing years.

Comment: Depending on your system, the `gmtime` family of functions *might* have trouble with years before 1902 or after 2038. If your perl is one of these and there's any chance you'll be dealing with centenarians, you might want to use `DateTime` for safety.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.55/lib/DateTime.pm)? It'll handle parsing as well as subtraction.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I had not tried it no but I will keep it in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime and DateTime::Duration.

When you substract a DateTime::Duration from a DateTime you get an other DateTime.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Duration;

my $fmt = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%d %b %Y',
    locale  => 'en_US',
);

my $start = $fmt->parse_datetime($ARGV[0]);
my $age = DateTime::Duration->new(years => $ARGV[1]);

my $birth = $start - $age;
print $fmt->format_datetime($birth), "\n";
```

Here is an example on how to invoke it:

```
$ perl birth.pl "25 Nov 2005" 74.23
25 Sep 1931
$ perl birth.pl "21 Jan 2007" 75.38
21 Sep 1931
```

Comment: Hummm, you are using ` $age = DateTime::Duration->new(years => $ARGV[1]);` and $ARGV[1] is 74.23, BUT the manual for Date::Manip for new( ... ) says:<cite>

This method takes the parameters "years", "months", "weeks", "days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds", "nanoseconds", and "end_of_month". All of these except "end_of_month" are numbers. If any of the numbers are negative, the entire duration is negative.

**All of the numbers must be integers.**</cite> Are you seen any problem when using non integer numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I'd second Oesor's recommendation (second time today), and reiterate mobrule's reminder that perl handles negative dates. So [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) is preferable.

But I would like to illustrate that this can be done with [`POSIX::mktime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX#mktime):

```
my ( $year1, $mon1, $day1 ) = qw<1944 7 1>;
my ( $year2, $mon2, $day2 ) = qw<2006 5 4>;

my $time1 = POSIX::mktime( (0) x 3, $day1, $mon1 - 1, 72 );
my $time2 = POSIX::mktime( (0) x 3, $day2, $mon2 - 1, 72 );
my $years = $year2 - $year1 - ( $time2 < $time1 ? 1 : 0 );
# 61 years
```

The caveat is that perl's internal clock handles dates back to December 14th, 1902 (actually 13th, after noon and before 6 PM), before which mktime starts returning `undef`. So for 99% of the people alive today, this will probably do.

**Pointless trivia:** `scalar localtime( 0x80000000 ) : 'Fri Dec 13 15:45:52 1901'` <- that's the cutoff ( `0x80000000` being 2s-complement minimum integer )